# XSLT conditional test

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

Is my exam answer correct?

### Given Input XML:

```
<weather> 

<date>2011-07-14T8:00</date> 

<region sky="sunny">

 <name>Karlsruhe</name>
 <temperature>26.54</temperature>

</region>

<region sky="rainy">
  <name>Stuttgart</name> 
  <temperature>12.54</temperature>

</region>

<region sky="sunny">
   <name>Freiburg</name>
   <temperature>40</temperature> 

 </region>
 </weather>
```

### required:

e) XSLT (20 Points)
Write an XSL transformation that receives the given XML as input and puts out text with all region names that have a temperature of at least 24 degree celsius. For the above XML the output should look as follows:
Karlsruhe: 26.54 
Freiburg: 24.21

### my answer i don't know if it correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <output method="text"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">


  <xsl:for-each select="weather/region">
  <xsl:if test="temperature>30">

      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="temperature"/>

  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

i am not sure if I should use

```
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:value-of select="temperature"/>
```

or 
      `<apply-template select="name"/> :  <apply-template select="temperature"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ok, except that the `output` element needs its namespace prefix:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

and the instructions say "at least 24 degrees", so that would be:

```
<xsl:if test="temperature >= 24">
```

In order to output the values correctly, I'd suggest using `concat()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="weather/region">
    <xsl:if test="temperature >= 24">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, ': ', temperature, ' ')"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A slightly better approach would be to use templates and XPath selection to evaluate the condition, though I'm not sure if that would be beyond the scope of your course:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="weather/region[temperature >= 24]" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="region">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, ': ', temperature, ' ')" />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: but a small question in 2nd solution : when typing   <xsl:apply-templates select="weather/region[temperature >= 24]" />
 wouldnt that already print the output we want but without (:)...why did we need to open another template that match region and use value-of ? thank u so much , u have no idea how much u helped me

Comment: `apply-templates` selects all the nodes indicated by the specified XPath and looks for templates that match those nodes. If no matching templates are defined, the default behavior is to output all of those nodes' text content (it's a little more involved than that, but that's the general idea). In order to output them in a specific way (with the colon and space), I defined a template to match `region` nodes.  We didn't _have to_ create a separate template for the regions, but that is the preferred way to write XSLTs because it keeps them well organized.